# RSA Decryption in iPhone using public key

Tags: iphone, rsa, encryption, public-key

I have public key and encrypted data and i have to decrypt that data with Public key. As data is being encrypted with RSA in Server side so i have to decrypt with RSA in iPhone. I have googled but didn't got any good solution. I have gone through CryptoExercise provided by Apple but still not able to find out solution.
Pls guys help me to implement this decryption.

**EDIT:** Over Server, data is encrypted with Private key.

Comment: Which RSA format do you have your data in? PKCS #1? PKCS #7? #12?

Comment: Typically, encryption is done using the public key, unless you are doing it as part of a digital signature.  I'd verify that this is the setup you want if you're concerned about the security of your data.

Comment: Thanks Shadowman.. We are doing it as a part of Digital signature. So i need to verify authenticity of a data in iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

First, see Chris Luke's write up of [how to turn a PKCS1 into iOS's non-standard key form](http://blog.flirble.org/2011/01/05/rsa-public-key-openssl-ios/). You can then use the resulting `SecKeyRef` with `SecKeyDecrypt`.

Comment: This is not PKCS #1, which you indicated. PKCS #1 is encoded in ASN.1. See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3447#appendix-A.1.1. You need to rework your question to be clear about the nature of what you have and what you're trying to achieve. Is it verification or decryption? What format is this? Your question does not match your comments.